# symbols in sbt scala not recognized in intellij 13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I created a project based on a valid sbt scala project. However, a few symbols like `dependsOn` or `mapR` are not recognized inside intellij 13.

[image]

Could anybody please help?

Comment: Please describe the method you used to create the project.

Comment: I take an existing project, then chooser "import project", and "from existing model" > "sbt project", and used "auto import". That is the whole process.

Comment: Do you have sbt.version=0.13.0 (or whatever your version is) in project/build.properties ?

Comment: yes, i do. I have `sbt.version=0.12.4` in that file

Answer (score 0):

If your code is valid and compiles, then this simply means either your class path is incorrect, or that IntelliJ's error highlighting is not resolving references as expected. Please raise an issue within the Jetbrain's [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard) system if this is the case.

As a shortcut, this can be achieved with the shortcut alt+enter, and selecting the option "Report Highlighting Error..."